# Quais as diferenças entre Promise.all() e Promise.allSettled()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Estou fazendo uns testes com **Promises** e me deparei que há duas formas de obter o resultado de um conjunto de promises:

usando `Promise.all()`:

```
async searchSegmentsInformations(segmentId) {
    try {
      const segment = await Segment.find(segmentId);
      return segment;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }

  testePromises() {
    const segmentsIds = [
      { id: 'bd84f021-30fb-4dad-b21a-6d673610db93' },
      { id: '25fcd038-58c2-44c2-aa9b-43529d591ed3' },
      { id: 'e1e9fd46-63ad-4ad9-af85-a16bd71a5b22' },
      { id: 'ca9f3a88-cb91-465a-87be-0c4bcfefa299' }
    ];

    const teste = Promise.all(
      segmentsIds.map((s) => this.searchSegmentsInformations(s.id))
    )
      .then((result) => {
        return result
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    return teste;
  }
```

com `Promise.allSettled()`:

```
async searchSegmentsInformations(segmentId) {
    try {
      const segment = await Segment.find(segmentId);
      return segment;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }

  testePromises() {
    const segmentsIds = [
      { id: 'bd84f021-30fb-4dad-b21a-6d673610db93' },
      { id: '25fcd038-58c2-44c2-aa9b-43529d591ed3' },
      { id: 'e1e9fd46-63ad-4ad9-af85-a16bd71a5b22' },
      { id: 'ca9f3a88-cb91-465a-87be-0c4bcfefa299' }
    ];

    const teste = Promise.allSettled(
      segmentsIds.map((s) => this.searchSegmentsInformations(s.id))
    )
      .then((result) => {
        const segmentsInformations = result.map((r) => r.value);
        return segmentsInformations;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    return teste;
  }
```

Qual a diferença entre os dois? 
Ambos possuem a mesma compatibilidade? 
Quando devo usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Basicamente, `Promise.all` e `Promise.allSettled` são dois entre os chamados [”combinadores de promessas”](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators). Em síntese, `Promise.all` retornará um *array* com os valores de resultado de todas as promessas passadas. Ele irá rejeitar caso qualquer uma delas falhe. Já `Promise.allSettled` retornará uma lista com informações relativas a todas as promessas passadas, não importando se foram resolvidas ou rejeitadas.

## [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

A função `Promise.all` recebe um iterável (como um array) de promessas e, uma vez que *todas* tenham sido resolvidas, retorna um novo array com os respectivos valores de resolução. Caso uma delas falhar, `Promise.all` fará um ”curto circuito”, de modo que rejeitará com o motivo de falha da primeira delas.

`Promise.all` foi introduzido no padrão ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), juntamente com o próprio objeto `Promise`.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
const promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.resolve(3),
];

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((list) => {
    console.log('Result:');
    console.log(list);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Agora note que se qualquer uma das promessas do iterável fornecido falhar, `Promise.all` também rejeitará, com o motivo da primeira falha:

```js
const promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.reject('Eu vou falhar e arruinar tudo.'),
  Promise.resolve(3),
];

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((list) => {
    console.log('Result:');
    console.log(list);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

## [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

A função `Promise.allSettled`, de modo similar à `Promise.all`, também recebe um iterável de promessas e espera que todas sejam concluídas. A diferença é que retorna um array de objetos, descrevendo o resultado de cada uma das promessas. Esse objeto tem duas propriedades:

- `status`, que indica o resultado da promessa. Pode assumir o valor `fulfilled` no caso da resolução da promessa ou `reject` no caso de sua rejeição;
- `value`, o valor do resultado da promessa.

Portanto, `Promise.allSettled` resolve somente após *todas* as promessas  passadas tenham um resultado. Ao contrário de `Promise.all`, que só resolve se todas as promessas tenham sido resolvidas, `Promise.allSettled` resolve com resoluções e/ou rejeições.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
const promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.reject('Eu vou falhar, mas NÃO vou arruinar tudo.'),
  Promise.resolve(3),
];

Promise.allSettled(promises)
  .then((list) => {
    console.log('Result:');
    console.log(list);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

O método `Promise.allSettled`, diferentemente do `Promise.all`, é bem mais recente. Foi introduzido no ECMAScript 2020. Consulte a [tabela de suporte](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_allsettled) para ver se o seu ambiente suporte esse método antes de utilizá-lo.

## Sobre <s>o paralelismo</s> a concorrência dessas funções

Funções como `Promise.all` e `Promise.allSettled` **não** executam as promessas de forma paralela. JavaScript é *single-threaded*, de modo que não há paralelismo – promessas não quebram essa invariante.

Contudo, utilizar funções como a `Promise.all` permite **concorrência**. De acordo com [esta definição](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050257/7445826), isso significa que as promessas podem iniciar, executar e terminar em tempos interpolados. Veja que isso não significa que são executadas *ao mesmo tempo*.

Vale lembrar, também, que funções como as descritas nesta resposta *não iniciam* as promessas. Elas recebem um iterável de promessas *já criadas*, e apenas aguardam que todas sejam concluídas (no caso de `allSettled`) para fazer algo.

As promessas já são criadas antes de serem passadas à função. É importante saber disso.

## Conclusão

Se por algum motivo você quiser executar alguma ação caso uma lista de tarefas for executada com 100% de êxito, utilize `Promise.all`, que irá te garantir isso.

Se você precisar de executar uma lista completa de promessas, não importando se foram resolvidas ou rejeitadas, `Promise.allSettled` será o seu amigo.

Veja os links pela resposta para aprofundamento.

Comment: Essa explicação foi muito boa, obrigado. Só para esclarecer: No caso da Promise.all(), não importa quantas promises venham a falhar, ela irá parar já na 1ª falha e retornar o error apenas dessa 1ª falha, certo?

Comment: Sim, @Diogo. Isso mesmo.